# how to align to the right action bar items title or label?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, right-to-left

I want to align to the right the titles of the items I am presenting on the action bar under app:showAsAction="never".

I am not trying to align differently the App action bar title or do something anti-pattern, just present RTL Hebrew Strings inside the drop down settings list.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You can try [android:supportsRtl](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html)